# Bootstrap menu not opening

Tags: menu, bootstrap-4

This is a non-Wordpress bootstrap project:  The top menu displays fine in the full browser but doesn't open (drop down) in the mobile, small screen view. [http://www.mjstrauss.com](http://www.mjstrauss.com/)

Any help will be so appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery reference below is broken:
http://www.mjstrauss.com/js/jquery.js

Try replacing it with:
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js